# Betti numbers of threefolds with trivial canonical class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, calabi-yau

I am interested in a simply-connected compact complex manifold $M$ of dimension three with trivial canonical class.
Note that if it is K"ahler, then it is a  Calabi-Yau threefold.
Its independent Betti numbers are $b_2, b_3$ and $b_3$ is a positive number.

I am interested in cases where $b_2, b_3$ are particularly small.

When $b_2=0$, Examples with $b_3 = 4, 6, 8 ...$ are constructed by  Lu and Tian.

When $b_2 =1$ (which is the next simplest case), the classification seems wide open. I am wondering if an example with $b_3=2$ exists in this case.

Let me state my question precisely:

> Is there any known example with $b_2=1, b_3=2$? If not,  is there any possible reason that such an example does not exist?

Comment: "It is known that an example with $b_3=2$ does not exist" : could you give a reference for that? And why does Serre duality imply $b_3>0$?

Comment: The paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00892.pdf constructs a projective Calabi-Yau threefold with $b_2=b_3=2$. But it is not simply connected. At least in the projective case, the examples with small Hodge numbers I am aware of almost always use a free action on a larger CY3 to cut down the number of divisors. See for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06303.pdf.

Comment: @abx: if $X$ is a compact complex manifold whose canonical bundle has a non-zero holomorphic section then the real and imaginary parts are closed and give two independent elements in middle degree de Rham cohomology. In particular, in the case the OP is interested in, $b_3 \geq 2$.

Comment: In a paper I wrote with Dima Panov, you can find infinitely many distinct complex structures with trivial canonical bundle on the manifold $2(S^3\times S^3)\#(S^2 \times S^4)$. This has $b_2=1$ and $b_3 = 4$. See https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3237.

Comment: @Joel Fine: Thank you (for $b_3\geq 2$), I should have thought of that! But I was trying to see a relation with Serre duality...

Comment: @abx, according to Wall's classification theorem(Classification problem in Topology V),   $M$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3 \times S^3$ if $H_2(M; \mathbb Z) =0$ and $H_3(M; \mathbb Z)$ is torsion-free (These conditions for cohomologies are missing in the original post -- now edited). Hence $M$ is a Calabi–Eckmann manifold but its canonical class is not trivial.
And For the part "$b_3 >0$" with Serre duality, I was mistaken. Now edited.

Comment: How do you conclude that for any complex structure on $S^3 \times S^3$ the canonical bundle is non-trivial?

Comment: @Aleksandar Milivojević, I've got your point. The post is edited.